# Regarding actions on posts flagged as low quality

Tags: discussion

Just wanted to consult regarding reviewing answers flagged as low quality. More often than not, I encounter these answers on review queues for low quality posts:
[image]
There are only 3 given actions for these type of answers:

- Looks OK - This, however, does not look OK so option 1 is out.
- Edit - Option 2 can be picked but for me, I think its kinda hard to edit this without deviating from the author's intent (and if you knew the answer, it might be best to just post an answer instead). Most one can probably do is provide grammar corrections and all but, it would still be a low-quality answer.
- Recommend deletion - Option 3 is also a no-go since this post can still be fixed if the OP will edit it. I learned not to be trigger-happy with this option.

My question, then, is: should the option to let the OP know that his answer can use some editing be a valid review action for Low Quality Posts queue?

In First Posts queues, for example, providing a comment to the question/answer to let the OP know of possible improvements for the post would count as an action. The same kind of comment to the item in the Low Quality Posts queue can be provided but then, it will be as if no review has been done on the item since the action done was not among the three choices. So, the queue will still have this item even though the reviewer has already let the OP know the problems in his/her post.

Comment: Even if a post is deleted, the poster can edit the post and can get the post undeleted. (Unless a moderator deletes the post, IIRC, then a moderator has to undelete)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would leave a comment manually then either just leave the task or skip it. That way, OP gets a chance to improve it, and it stays in the queue so later on if they fixed it, someone can mark it as "OK" and if they didn't, someone can delete.

Even if a post is on the border, if there's no clear way to edit it (add a citation for something that is true, fix some spelling or grammar that makes it hard to understand, etc), then it's either OK or should be deleted. There is a grey area where it's hard to decide, but it's not that no decision can be made, it's just that it's a very close call and thus hard to decide. If you aren't confident, I would skip and leave it for someone else. Worst case, nobody's sure, and a moderator comes along and decides. We're here to handle these exceptions anyway :)

Whenever I delete posts on my site (usually since OP has not addressed concerns), I'll leave a comment letting them know what's wrong and that if they fix it, they can flag it for a moderator to undelete the post, and I would advise the same here - leave a comment explaining the issue, and if it's not fixed, comment again and delete (although since you can't vote to delete yet, I don't think you can see if your delete action would delete the post - this is mostly a suggestion for people casting the third deletion vote, or moderators, and I don't know if this is that applicable to A&M, this is mostly a policy I follow on Code Golf which is a bit different).

In this specific example, I would leave a comment for the OP and if they don't fix it, recommend deletion. The post contains no sources or evidence for its claims and doesn't explain anything; I would expect an answer of quality worth keeping around to either cite a source for Aniplex being busy with other works, or a timeline for when the work in this discussion will be dubbed, or an explanation as to why Aniplex is putting off this work until it is finished dubbing other anime, et cetera.